# Preventing "open in new tab" on a non-anchor element

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Clicking my button triggers function `handleSubmit()` which displays a modal.

However I've just been told that on smartphone, it's unfortunately possible to hold-tap (I have no idea how to express this) then select "open in new tab".

Of course the new tab shows an error page. How to prevent this action, that is, allowing users to tap but not to hold-tap?

```
<div
  class="button"
  @click="handleSubmit"
>
  Click
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a demo? Are buttons even supposed to have that option?

Comment: May be irrelevant, but I'm curious why you'd use a `<div class="button">` instead of using an actual `<button>` element?